How to define return type of Nuxt custom useFetch composable?
I created an api plugin and useApi composable and now I try to set the typescript return type.
// plugins/01.api.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const api = $fetch.create({
        baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().public.baseUrl,
    });

    return {
        provide: {
            api
        }
    }
})

// composables/useAPI.ts
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app';

export function useAPI<TResponse, T>(
    url: string | (() => string),
    options?: UseFetchOptions<T>,
): Promise<TResponse> {
    return useFetch(url, {
        ...options,
        $fetch: useNuxtApp().$api
    });
}

// use case example
interface fooBar {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

async function initFooBar() {
    const { data } = await useAPI<fooBar>('/example-call');
    console.log(data.value.data);
}

But the data type keeps to be of type const data: any. How to specify the type?
Update:
I made it work by defining the response object like this, but it dont feel like the cleanest solution
export function useAPI<TResponse, T>(
    url: string | (() => string),
    options?: UseFetchOptions<T>,
): Promise<{ data: { value: TResponse | null } } & FetchResult<TResponse>> {
    return useFetch<TResponse>(url, {
        ...options,
        $fetch: useNuxtApp().$api
    }) as Promise<{ data: { value: TResponse | null } } & FetchResult<TResponse>>;
}

